Convert Swift OpenAPIRuntime.HTTPBody into JSON-String
I'm using Apple's Open API Generator in my iOS mobile app.
I need to convert the http response in case of a failure from the backend, for this I have the following implementation:
switch response {
case .internalServerError(let error):
case .badRequest(let badRequest):
case .created(let player):
case .undocumented(statusCode: let statusCode, let payload):
}

The http response is of type OpenAPIRuntime.HTTPBody and I don't know how to convert it into a String or other Type. Does anyone know how?

The OpenAPIRuntime has a Converter.getResponseBodyAsJSON, which should do what you're looking for.

Try this implementation:
switch response {
case .internalServerError(let error):
    // Handle internal server error
    print("Internal Server Error: \(convertToJSONString(httpBody: error))")
case .badRequest(let badRequest):
    // Handle bad request
    print("Bad Request: \(convertToJSONString(httpBody: badRequest))")
case .created(let player):
    // Handle success case
    print("Created: \(convertToJSONString(httpBody: player))")
case .undocumented(statusCode: let statusCode, let payload):
    // Handle undocumented cases
    print("Undocumented Status Code: \(statusCode), Payload: \(convertToJSONString(httpBody: payload))")
}

// Helper function to convert HTTPBody to JSON String
func convertToJSONString(httpBody: OpenAPIRuntime.HTTPBody) -> String {
    guard let data = httpBody.data else {
        return "No Data"
    }
    
    // Convert data to a string
    if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        return jsonString
    } else {
        return "Unable to convert data to String"
    }
}

example:
func convertToJSON(httpBody: OpenAPIRuntime.HTTPBody) -> Any? {
    guard let data = httpBody.data else {
        return nil
    }
    
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        return json
    } catch {
        print("Failed to convert to JSON: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}

